# Show $A$ is unbounded given $\int_A f'(x) dx \leq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-empty open set such that 
$$\int_A f'(x) dx \leq 0$$
for all $f\in\mathcal{C}_c^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f\geq 0$. Prove that $A$ is unbounded.

The hint says first show when $A=(a,b)$.
We would have
$$\int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b) - f(a) \leq 0$$
for all $f\in\mathcal{C}_c^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f\geq 0$, which is impossible.

Now for the general case $A$, I am not sure how to connect it to the hint.

Intuitively, I think $A$ has to have "mass" up to $+\infty$ to capture the decreasing of $f$ from positive to zero since $f$ is non-negative and has compact support, so that we have $\int_A f'(x) dx \leq 0$.

Any hint is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, what is $\mathcal{C}^1_c$ ? what does the little $c$ at the bottom stand for?

Comment: @ant The $c$ means compact support, the function is zero outside of a compact set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded, then it is contained in an interval. If $A\subset (a,b)$ then consider a function $f$ which is smooth, positive, with compact support and such that $f(x)=x+(1-a)$ on $(a,b)$. Thus $\int_Af'=\int_A1>0$ because $A$ is open and hence has positive measure. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

For general bounded open set $A$, we can write $A=\cup_{i} (a_i, b_i)$, and there exists an open interval $G$ st $\cup_{i} (a_i, b_i) \subseteq G$. so we can find a $C_c^1$ function st $G\subseteq supp(f)$ and $f(b_i)>f(a_i), i=1,2,\cdots$, $\int_A f = \sum_i f(b_i)- f(a_i)>0$, which is contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking this... From my institutive idea, suppose $A$ is bounded above, let $a:= \sup A$. Then we can define a smooth function with compact support which is only increasing up to the point $a$.

And thank you guys for the reply!